# Django UpdateView does not save new data when testing

Tags: django

When I use my application on running server to update existing entry it works but when I run the test it creates entry, post it but does not update the fields title and author so I get an assertion error. When I compare prints from updating on running application and test I can't notice any difference.

**MODEL**:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    published = models.IntegerField(validators=[MaxValueValidator(datetime.date.today().year)],
                                    help_text="Use the following format: YYYY")
    isbn_10 = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, verbose_name='ISBN_10')
    isbn_13 = models.CharField(max_length=13, null=True, verbose_name='ISBN_13')
    cover_uri = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    language = models.CharField(max_length=56)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=120, unique=True, blank=True)
```

**TEST:**

```
def test_update_book(self):
    """Create book object and updates fields with correct data"""

    book = Book.objects.create(title='Camera Work 1',
                               author='Alfred Stieglitz',
                               published='2008',
                               isbn_10='',
                               isbn_13='9788389192868',
                               cover_uri='image.jpg',
                               language='english')

    response = self.client.post(
        reverse('books-update', kwargs={'slug': book.slug}),
        {'title': 'The Catcher in the Rye',
         'author': 'J.D. Salinger',
         'published': '2008',
         'isbn_10': '',
         'isbn_13': '9788389192868',
         'cover_uri': 'image.jpg',
         'language': 'english'})

    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)

    book.refresh_from_db()
    print('BOOK', book)
    self.assertEqual(book.author, 'J.D. Salinger')
```

**URL PATTERN:**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('update/<str:slug>', BookUpdateView.as_view(), name='books-update'),
]
```

**AND VIEW:**

```
class BookUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = Book
    fields = '__all__'
    success_url = '/'
    template_name = 'books/book_update.html'

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        print('POST', request.POST, kwargs)
        return super().post(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

When I use my template to update that entry it works but when I run the test it creates entry, post it but does not update the fields `title` and `author` so I get

**AN ERROR:**

```
AssertionError: 'Alfred Stieglitz' != 'J.D. Salinger'
- Alfred Stieglitz
+ J.D. Salinger
```

**HERE ARE PRINTS FROM TESTS**

```
POST <QueryDict: {'title': ['The Catcher in the Rye'], 'author': ['J.D. Salinger'],
 'published': ['2008'], 'isbn_10': [''], 'isbn_13': ['9788389192868'], 'cover_uri': 
['image.jpg'], 'language': ['english']}> {'slug': 'camera-work-1'}

BOOK Camera Work 1, Alfred Stieglitz, 2008
```

Comment: Could the save only be triggered when a certain button on the BookUpdateView template is pushed?

Comment: I found what's wrong. My model has an `isbn_10` field that is `required field` and in my `post data` it is empty so the  `save` method throws an error and doesn't update.